# Oreo: When I use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW, notification does not appear in the status bar

Tags: android, notifications

When I use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW to disable the sound, the notification not appear in the status bar. When I see the setting of a channel I have: Medium  No sound.

Here all my code

```
     Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

                                    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                                    NotifCmtManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                        if(!checkGroupSon) {
                                             /* Create or update. */
                                            mChannel = new NotificationChannel("comment", "YuYu", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                                            mChannel.enableLights(true);
                                            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);

                                            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                                            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});


                                            assert mChannel != null;
                                            notificationBuilder.setChannelId("comment");
                                            NotifCmtManager.deleteNotificationChannel("noS");
                                            NotifCmtManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

                                        }else{

                                                  /* Create or update. */
                                           mChannel = new NotificationChannel("noS", "YuYu No Sound", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
                                            mChannel.enableLights(true);
                                            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);

                                            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                                            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

                                            //   mChannel.setSound(null,null);
                                            mChannel.enableVibration(true);


                                            assert mChannel != null;
                                            notificationBuilder.setChannelId("noS");
                                          NotifCmtManager.deleteNotificationChannel("comment");
                                            NotifCmtManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);


                                        }
                                    }
                                    NotifCmtManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATIONCMT, notification);
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: disable the sound of notification and it appears in the status bar

Comment: I don't know if it's causing issues, but the channel ID you're deleting is different than the one you're creating

Comment: No it 's not causing issues, I have two channel: one with IMPORTANCE_LOW and anotther with IMPORTANCE_HIGH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IMPORTANCE_LOW` notification will only be displayed in the status bar if there aren't other higher-importance notifications filling all the status bar space.

To raise the chances of your notification's icon being displayed in the status bar you can use a `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` channel. To disable the sound you can set a `null` sound to the channel:

```
mChannel = new NotificationChannel("comment_notSound", "YuYu No Sound",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
mChannel.setSound(null, null);
```

Comment: I have a same problem(not appear) with IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT while in the parameter I have :High    Makes a sound

Comment: Also when I use IMPORTANCE_HIGH in my second channel for test, I have a same problem: no sound and notification not appear while in setting I have : Urgent  Makes a sound and appears as a heads-up notification.

Comment: Two things came to my mind: 
First: Is the notification being displayed in the notification tray?
Second: If I got it correctly, even when you change the code, the content on App Info -> Notifications doesn't change. Have you tried uninstalling the app and installing it again to check if anything changes?

Comment: No it's not display in the notification tray. In app info, notification change because title change

Comment: If the notification is not being displayed at all, the notification channel might not be the only problem.